# How to increment/decrement the likes and dislikes of the button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> i want to achieve increase number in likes and decrease number in
>   dislikes.
>   i have implemented the setState
>    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toRWi.png)

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Row, Col, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardSubtitle, Button } from 'reactstrap';
        import index from './index.css'

        class MovieList extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          }
          state ={
              count:0
          }

          incrementMe = () => {
            let newCount = this.state.count + 1
            this.setState({
              count: newCount
            })
          }
          decrementMe = () => {
            let newCount = this.state.count - 1
            this.setState({
              count: newCount
            })
          }

          render () {
            let { id, title, category, likes} = this.props.movie;
            return (
              <div>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader><strong>{title}</strong></CardHeader>
                   <CardBody>
                    <CardSubtitle>{category}</CardSubtitle>
                    <Button> : {this.state.count}</Button> &nbsp;
                    <Button> : {this.state.count}</Button>
                    <br />
                    <Button color="danger" onClick={() => this.props.removeMovie(id)}>Delete</Button>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }

        export default MovieList;
```

> the image i attached is the output of the present code
>   the following code is the movies list which i implemented into the
>   cards

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import MovieList from './MovieList';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: [
        {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Oceans 8',
        category: 'Comedy',
        likes: 4,
        dislikes: 1
      }, {
        id: '2',
        title: 'Midnight Sun',
        category: 'Comedy',
        likes: 2,
        dislikes: 0
      }, {
        id: '3',
        title: 'Les indestructibles 2',
        category: 'Animation',
        likes: 3,
        dislikes: 1
      }, {
        id: '4',
        title: 'Sans un bruit',
        category: 'Thriller',
        likes: 6,
        dislikes: 6
      }, {
        id: '5',
        title: 'Creed II',
        category: 'Drame',
        likes: 16,
        dislikes: 2
      }, {
        id: '6',
        title: 'Pulp Fiction',
        category: 'Thriller',
        likes: 11,
        dislikes: 3
      }, {
        id: '7',
        title: 'Pulp Fiction',
        category: 'Thriller',
        likes: 12333,
        dislikes: 32
      }, {
        id: '8',
        title: 'Seven',
        category: 'Thriller',
        likes: 2,
        dislikes: 1
      }, {
        id: '9',
        title: 'Inception',
        category: 'Thriller',
        likes: 2,
        dislikes: 1
      }, {
        id: '10',
        title: 'Gone Girl',
        category: 'Thriller',
        likes: 22,
        dislikes: 12
      }
      ]
    }
  }
  removeMovie(id) {
    this.setState({ movies: this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.id !== id)});
  }
  render () {
    let MovieLists = this.state.movies.map(movie => {
      return (
        <Col md="4">
          <MovieList key={movie.id} removeMovie={this.removeMovie.bind(this)} movie={movie} />
        </Col>

      )
    })
    return (
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          {MovieLists}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

> Please try to help me with the increase in likes and decrease in
>   dislikes(number with existing likes and dislikes)

Comment: You are using the same `count` for both like and dislike. You need to create a separate state variable for like and dislikes. Also, I would not do something like this as the value is being passed as a prop so I would rather pass function from parent component as handler and let it do the magic. If you want to understand better let me know, I will post the snippet as well. Thanks

Comment: You rather push id to the likes and dislikes to keep track who's liking and disliking the post. In this case, you can just remove from array if the user click the button again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it might help you to see the code structured in a slightly different way as @Bharat23 mentioned earlier so I have created a Sandbox for you to have a look at that just does the like/dislike functionality in local state. In a real application you would validate that the user hadn't voted before and get the movie data from an external source that you update so this is very simplistic but I hope that it helps in some way.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-glitter-3ievf?fontsize=14

Comment: how do you put both the increment and decrement in one button, so that the number can only increase once and decrease once, instead of increasing on every click.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts a little tricky to perform calculations in Javascript when the value can change to `>0` 0r `0` on the same field. So you have to carefully set the right conditions to prepare and take care of these situations.

```
incrementMe = () => {
    var newCount = this.state.coun
    function like () {
        if (newCount !== 0) {
          return newCount+=1
        }
        else {
          return 1
        }
    }
    this.setState({
      count: like()
   })
}
```

On dislike you can do the following.

```
decrementMe = () => {
   var newCount = this.state.count
   function dislike () {
     if (newCount !== 0) {
       return newCount-=1
     }
     else {
      return -1
    }
  }
   this.setState({
     count: dislike()
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write increment count of `likes` and `dislikes` into parent component only and pass those functions to child component.

```
<MovieList key={movie.id} removeMovie={this.removeMovie.bind(this)} movie={movie} likeMe={this.likeMe.bind(this)} dislikeMe={this.dislikeMe.bind(this)}/>
```

And function should be,

```
likeMe = (id) => {
    var index = this.state.movies.findIndex(movie => movie.id === id);
    if (index === -1) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        this.setState({
            movies: [
                ...this.state.movies.slice(0, index),
                Object.assign({}, this.state.movies[index], { likes: this.state.movies[index].likes + 1 }),
                ...this.state.movies.slice(index + 1)
            ]
        });
    }
}
dislikeMe = (id) => {
    var index = this.state.movies.findIndex(movie => movie.id === id);
    if (index === -1) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        this.setState({
            movies: [
                ...this.state.movies.slice(0, index),
                Object.assign({}, this.state.movies[index], { dislikes: this.state.movies[index].dislikes + 1 }),
                ...this.state.movies.slice(index + 1)
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

In child component,

```
<Button onClick={()=>this.props.likeMe(id)}> : {likes}</Button> &nbsp;
<Button onClick={()=>this.props.dislikeMe(id)}> : {dislikes}</Button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rmalbb)

---

**Note:** **On `dislike` button press, it is common that we increase the count of `dislike` instead of decresing the count. I also did the same, I increases the count on dislike button press like `{ dislikes: this.state.movies[index].dislikes + 1 }`. If you still go with anti-pattern and want to decrease the count do this `{ dislikes: this.state.movies[index].dislikes - 1 }`, in this case you need to handle minus count.**